# RavenDB and batch API

Tags: import, ravendb, batch-processing

Hi in my project we are doing an import if lets say products.

We will have a web service where we will get maybe 10 calls for one import, so we need to have a transaction that can be over several requests.

The import will have both new products that needs to be created and existing products that needs to be updated.

Right now the only way we can know if the product is already in our system or not is to look at Name or Previous Name on the Product we want to import.

So basically my questions is.

Can the transaction API described here http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/databasecommands, Be used for the Batch api described here http://ravendb.net/docs/1.0/client-api/advanced/databasecommands/batch. (which it sounds not to work together if one read the batch api documentation).

And if not should I use the database commands connected with an transaction? But in the documentation for databasecommands I can't see how the transaction guid and the operations can be connected?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle that is to aggregate things in memory and have just a single SaveChanges call in the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was my conclusion also when have read the documentation. But we would rather not aggregate everything in memory and would rather like to batch items to the store but have several batches in one transaction. The third part will for example call us with a unique id of the import session and send us a number of items, and we would like to use ravendb the same way, maybe create an transaction use the guid to store and with the session and just commit it when the last batch has come in. Isn't that possible?

Comment: How is RavenDB handling transactions on the ravendb server side. Will the data be in memory until the transaction is committed or will it be stored on disc?